# jsbeautifier and ejs compatibility

Tags: javascript, ejs, grunt-jsbeautifier

I am trying to use jsbeautifier to beautify my code and the main templating language I use is EJS. Perhaps I am mistaken but it doesn't seem to be that ejs is fully supported.

I am using this grunt plugin: https://github.com/vkadam/grunt-jsbeautifier

An example of the issue I am facing is that the beautifier seems to parse assignments oddly. I have this line of code:

```
<% page = english.about %>
```

and after beautification:

```
<% page=e nglish.about %>
```

This clearly breaks the template. I get the same result here: http://jsbeautifier.org/

I have no idea what part of the beautification process is parsing my code in what to me seems like such an unusual way. Part of what confuses me is if I have

```
<% page=english.about %>
```

The beautifier does nothing and my code runs correctly but it seems like a very poor practice to have to remember that while coding or everything breaks if I insert a space.

I have tried most of the configurations but nothing seems to fix this issue. I don't know of any beautifiers built specifically for ejs.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I can see why it's doing it: it's treating `<%` as an HTML element and for every HTML attribute it ensures there's no space either side of the `=`. The only thing I can think of is to [pass in the `unformatted` HTML config option](https://github.com/vkadam/grunt-jsbeautifier#default-options-from-js-beautify-can-be-used) like: `unformatted: ["%"]` and see if that works

Comment: Thanks Andy. I tried using unformatted but it didn't seam to make a difference. Odd that it inserts a space where it does. Oddly enough this just showed up in the repo: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/643. Apparently EJS is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been reported as an issue https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/643 there is a workaround for your problem (`<% page=e nglish.about %>`):

Just use parentheses like this:

`<% (page = english.about) %>`